# Is there a way to repeatedly force the browser into fullscreen mode?

Tags: html

I know there is a way to run the browser into fullscreen once, but i'm looking for a method which does it in a loop, so that the browser cannot exit fullscreen. This is for a project that uses fullscreen for it's experience and is using HTML5, and CSS3.

Comment: Forcing fullscreen mode doesn't seem like being best practice: the user will generally expect being able to exit the fullscreen mode, switch tabs or windows. Any particular reason you'd want to override the default behavior ?

Comment: If there is a state for checking fullscreen mode then there would be a way for it to set a condition. Like `if(!isFullscreenOn) {alert; return false;}`.